# KML : Schema expression in KML files

Tags: xsd, kml

I'm writing a package to programmatically create KML files.
The way I'm writing it is by reading the xsd file and generating the package code (this way, when the schema is updated, I can have a new package quickly and hopefully correctly).

Thus the interpretation of the schema's nuances is important to me for correctness' sake, and I need someone who knows this well to help.

There are several cases in the KML 2.2 XSD that motivate my question: DataExtension, SchemaDataExtension, SchemaExtension, SimpleFieldExtension, UpdateExtensionGroup, UpdateOpExtensionGroup

My question is about all of these, but using a specific example, what is the expression of the 'DataExtension' in a KML file in actual practice?

The XSD looks like:

```
<element name="ExtendedData" type="kml:ExtendedDataType"/>
<complexType name="ExtendedDataType" final="#all">
<sequence>
  <element ref="kml:Data" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <element ref="kml:SchemaData" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>

<element name="Data" type="kml:DataType" substitutionGroup="kml:AbstractObjectGroup"/>
<complexType name="DataType" final="#all">
<complexContent>
  <extension base="kml:AbstractObjectType">
    <sequence>
      <element ref="kml:displayName" minOccurs="0"/>
      <element ref="kml:value"/>
      <element ref="kml:DataExtension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="name" type="string"/>
  </extension>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
<element name="DataExtension" abstract="true"/>
```

Element DataExtension is abstract and has no type associated with it and it is not the name of a substitution group, thus there are no concrete bits of data it brings to the party anywhere to be found.  Yet the complexType 'DataType' allows me to add zero or more of them to any element including this type, in this case the element named 'Data'.

When emitting an element 'ExtendedData' which contains an element 'Data', how does the 'DataExtension' express itself?

```
<ExtendedData>                       
  <Data name="string">
    <displayName>...</displayName>    <!-- string -->
    <value>...</value>                <!-- string -->
    <?dataExtentionTag?>...</?dataExtentionTag?>    <! -- XXX -->
  </Data>
 ...    <! -- SchemaData can go here -->
</ExtendedData>
```

So at the XXX above, what would be the tag and what kind of data can go here and how would it be formatted in a proper KML document?  Where is there documentation on this level of detail?  (I've read the engineering report on KML 2.2 from http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/kml/ to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a substitutionGroup of DataExtension as an extension to KML with custom data elements.

Here's a simple example. An extended example would probably use a complexType for the extension element with its own custom attributes and/or elements as needed.

Simple example schema: ext.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

  xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
  targetNamespace="http://myextension"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  version="1.0">  

  <!-- Import the language we are extending: OGC KML 2.2 -->
  <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
    schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd" />

  <element name="MyData" type="string"
     substitutionGroup="kml:DataExtension"/>

</schema>
```

Example KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
  xmlns:ext="http://myextension"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://myextension ext.xsd
    http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd">
<Placemark>
      <name>Club house</name>      
      <ExtendedData>
        <Data name="holeNumber">
          <value>1</value>
          <ext:MyData>my data</ext:MyData>
        </Data>
        <Data name="holePar">
          <value>4</value>
          <ext:MyData>more data</ext:MyData>
        </Data>        
      </ExtendedData>
  </Placemark>    
</kml>
```

For more concrete examples see how Google implemented its own extensions.
https://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd

Comment: Thanks Jason.  This is what I was suspecting, but having validation is great.  In my package I'll just implement the ability to add (tag,value) elements in such cases.

Comment: If you provide a URL or absolute file reference to your schema in the xsi:schemaLocation element then a validating XML parser will validate the KML with your extensions.